# get nested JSON data in jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I have this JSON data:

```
[{"sequence":"503","accountnumber":"0001","telephonenumber":null,"emailaddress":"email@domain.com","directdebit":"Y","auto_directdebit":"","billing_address":{"title":"Mr","forename":"Joe","surname":" Bloggs","address1":"ADDR1","address2":"","address3":"","town":"TOWN","county":"COUNTY","postcode":"PC","country":"United Kingdom","default_invoice":"1","default_delivery":"1"}}]
```

And I use the following to retrieve the details:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/section/get_data?getCustomer=1&sequence=" + $("#customersequence").val(),
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data[0].accountnumber);
    }
});
```

which works but i cannot figure out how to return `billing_address`

i have tried:

```
data[0].billing_address[0].address1
```

but that did not work

how can i retrieve each field under `billing_address`

Comment: `data[0].billing_address` is an *object* with property `address1`.

Comment: parse JSON, when it returns data, it is plain string not JSON object

Comment: @Luminous_Dev Technical note: JSON is the *plain text* representing a serialized object graph. JavaScript objects are not JSON.

Comment: add `dataType: json` it is type definition for return value

Comment: @Luminous_Dev: Since the OP says that `alert(data[0].accountnumber);` works, we can assume that jQuery already parsed the JSON.

Comment: I recommend to review some [JavaScript data structure basics](http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are almost there, the only thing is that **billing_address** is not an array... remove the try to get the element with **[0]** like

```
data[0].billing_address.address1
```

Comment: worked great - thank you. i'll accept the answer when it allows me to in 10 minutes :)

Comment: @charlie, you are welcome :)